# Why won't my textfield save to my singleton?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I found, what I think to be, a decent example project on singleton classes [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html).

My question is:

What's up with

**- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField**

inside of the RootViewController.m and the SecondViewController.m (around lines 45-ish)?  I understand how it works, but I don't see how it ever gets called or used.

Comment: Please put the code you are talking about into the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

They are triggered by **delegation**. If you check the nib (in IB), you will see that it has delegate the first responder or the class (RootViewController or SecondViewController).

So what it does is listen to the textfield for once the user presses the OK button to trigger the method above (which is defined to UITextFieldDelegate protocol).

Comment: Yes, I did notice the delegation.  But I found delegate references inside of File Owner, not inside of First Responder.  Where exactly in First Responder would I find the delegate reference?

Comment: File Owner is ok (it happens there as well if you connect the text field delegate there). It means it's on the classes you mention above. I don't use IB often, so I define delegation differently.

Comment: Baah.  Yea.  If I had been smart I wouldn't have used IB either...I just don't get it because I think I have all of that.  The appropriate methods, the delegation connection from the text field to the file's owner, but when I try printing the string that gets saved on my project that function I have listed above never gets called.